# How to import text files in MS Excel with each line in a separate column?

Tags: excel, text-files

I have > 5000 [World files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) which are basically text files with 6 lines of data. I want to merge them all in one MS Excel file in the following format :

- 1st column : the World file name
- 2nd column : 1st line in the World file
- 3rd column : 2nd line in the World file
- 4th column : 3rd line in the World file
- 5th column : 4th line in the World file
- 6th column : 5th line in the World file
- 7th column : 6th line in the World file

With each line being one of the World file.

Is there a script that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First place your filespecs in *Sheet1* column **A** like:

[image]

and then with *Sheet1* selected, run this macro:

```
Sub WideWideWorld()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Dim s As String, j As Long, kk As Long

    kk = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Close #1
    For i = 1 To N
        k = 1
        s = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Open s For Input As #1
        For j = 1 To 6
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(kk, k).Value = TextLine
            k = k + 1
        Next j
        Close #1
        kk = kk + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

The output will be stored in *Sheet2*

I suggest starting with a small subset in *Sheet1* to see if the format meets your needs.

The routines pulls the first lines out of each file..........so be sure each file contains at least 6 lines.

Comment: It seems promising! I tried with 2 files, but it only copied the first 3 lines, separated by a column (column A contains line 1, column C contains line 2, column E contains line 3). The line 4, 5, and 6 are missing and the file name also. Any clue on what went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @Nahas It sounds like there is some kind of double-return between each record so the even records appear blank...........we can accommodate this is I can get my hands on an actual file!

Comment: If you need an actual file, you can download a sample world file here : http://www.charttiff.com/geolites/samples.shtml

Comment: @Nahas  Thanks I will update the code later the afternoon.

Comment: In your code, I changed "For j = 1 To 6" to "For j = 1 To 12" and I got all the lines imported. They are still separated by an empty column, but I can erase them by hand, so that’s not an issue. I got everything I need! Just one more question: **Is there a way to place my filespecs in Sheet1 column A automatically?** Like I said, I have over 5000 files, so copy/pasting the path one by one is not an option. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nahas ................It is easy **if the files are on a local mapped drive** like C:\whatever\, etc.

Comment: Yes I found the way to do it online. Thanks again!